# Having paragraph braking issue in project

Tags: css

I have a bug in my project where I've been asked to ensure that a paragraph does not break onto a new line for just a single word. Therefore, I need to remove that extra line and keep that word on its previous line. How can I achieve this globally using CSS?

I have tried to add overflow and few methods to resolve it nothing works

Comment: This may not be possible in HTML/CSS.

Comment: Your question is not clear pls provide your minimum HTML and css code to see the issue. You can have a look if that help at word-break: keep-all; etc..

Comment: This might be a use case for `text-wrap: pretty`. Although not fully supported yet.